# how to convert json response to List in c# RestSharp

Tags: sql, .net, api, restsharp

Currently I am working on asp .NET 5 console application with Restsharp, My Api Get request is working on postman, but I am struggling to convert this json object to a list .

This is my json object:

```
"data": {
        "domain": "intel.com",
        "disposable": false,
        "webmail": false,
        "accept_all": false,
        "pattern": "{first}.{last}",
        "organization": "Intel",
        "country": "US",
        "state": null,
        "emails": [
            {
                "value": "danielle.sikich@intel.com",
                "type": "personal",
                "confidence": 99,
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "domain": "github.com",
                        "uri": "http://github.com/hpc/mpifileutils",
                        "extracted_on": "2021-10-28",
                        "last_seen_on": "2021-10-28",
                        "still_on_page": true
                    }
                ],
                "first_name": "Danielle",
                "last_name": "Sikich",
                "position": null,
                "seniority": null,
                "department": null,
                "linkedin": null,
                "twitter": null,
                "phone_number": null,
                "verification": {
                    "date": "2021-11-05",
                    "status": "valid"
                }
            },
```

I tried this but its not working:

```
List<Job> JobList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(jsonResponse["data"]["emails"]["value"].ToString());
```

Comment: Well, first you need to fix that json because it contains errors. Second, you need to build the classes that could represent your json and finally you could deserialize to the root class. You can find many tools online that could help you [build a set of C# classes from a json](https://www.bing.com/search?q=create%20c%23%20class%20from%20json&qs=AS&sk=&pq=create%20c%23%20class%20from&sp=1&sc=8-20&form=BDKTKA&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: You have to put your complete json

Comment: Here I am working with Asp .NET MVC core application with [https://hunter.io/api-documentation/v2](https://hunter.io/api-documentation/v2) API, If I test this API on postman its working but with my application its not